# What are the recommended ways to get to the bottom of slow load times in EE?

Tags: debugging, loading-time, speed

I'm experiencing some really slow load times with my EE install. Other sections of the site that aren't managed by EE are loading very quickly, but any time I hit an EE-managed section it takes at least 6 seconds to load. After enabling debugging I'm seeing these results:

> **Loading Time: Base Classes** — 0.0023
>
> **Controller Execution Time ( Ee / Index )** — 6.1133
>
> **Total Execution Time** — 6.1158

What might be the best way to track down the source of these slow loading times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the EE Debug Toolbar. It's a great utility for seeing where your bottlenecks. Main place to check is memory consumption and db queries. My guess is it's a combination of both.

EE Debug Toolbar

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ee-debug-toolbar

The latest version of EE is also compatible with New Relic, check this out. It's software specifically designed for this and EE is compatible with it now.

https://newrelic.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would consider checking out the ExpressionEngine Whitepaper that Nexcess recently put out. It's a fairly in depth look at best practices for ExpressionEngine performance. Hope this helps. http://www.nexcess.net/expressionengine-best-practices-whitepaper

Answer (score 1):

Almost always optimize caching with the Devot-ee or Solspace addon best suited to your specific site needs is a good idea.  Read http://cdn.ctrlclickcast.com/transcripts/2011/eepodcast-055.pdf.